# For Loop for Formula that Changes Cell References

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to perform ratio analysis for a collection of financial statements, each of which are contained in a separate excel worksheet. The layout and format of each sheet is exactly the same. See below.

[Financial Statement Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iYuA.jpg)

For the ratio analysis section I have a separate worksheet where I want to make an array of the computed ratios. See below.

[Ratio Analysis Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Kl3.jpg)

Unfortunately, I really don’t want to click through each worksheet to create these formulas and would rather write a script with a FOR loop. Since I need to find a ratio for every year of the financial statement the formula itself will need to continuously shift columns to derive a ratio for every year.

This is where I’m stuck. I’m not sure how to loop through every cell of my ratio summary array and use a formula that also changes for each year of the financial statement. I’m thinking I need to make a nested for loop, but I’m really not sure how to attempt the script.

Can anyone do me a huge favor and suggest how I might even start planning this out?

[My VBA Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmwtV.jpg)

Here's what I have started, but I need more to figure this out. I don't think my formula will shift columns with this script, and I need help putting the computed values into the array on the ratio analysis sheet.

```
Sub Current_Ratio()

Dim Current_Ratio As Integer
Dim FirstYear As Long, LastYear As Long
FirstYear = 2015
LastYear = 2019

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name Like "*Balance Sheet*" Then
        For y = FirstYear To LastYear
            Current_Ratio = Worksheets(i).Range("F21").Value / Worksheets(i).Range("F51").Value
            'need line to place the computed current ratios into range B3:B37 on sheet17(Ratio Analysis)
        Next y
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to a formula solution rather than VBA? Here's how I would try it first. I say "try it" because the `INDIRECT()` function is slow and if you have too many formulas you might not like the performance. But I wouldn't make that judgement until I tried it.

[image: current ratio]

I have a sheet named `Company 1 Balance Sheet` and in B21:D21 I have 10, 15, and 20 respectively. In B51:D51 I have 20. I also have a sheet named `Company 2 Balance Sheet` that has the same numerators but 30 as the denominator.

Here is the formula in C2

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A2&" Balance Sheet'!"&CHAR(66+VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"T-",""),"yr","")))&"21")/INDIRECT("'"&A2&" Balance Sheet'!"&CHAR(66+VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"T-",""),"yr","")))&"51")
```

I started by pointing and clicking to build this formula

```
='Company 1 Balance Sheet'!B21/'Company 1 Balance Sheet'!B51
```

Then I used `INDIRECT` to build that formula as a string so I could change the inputs. Let's take just the numerator portion because it works the same for both. My company is in column A, so I can start by replacing that part of the formula

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A2&" Balance Sheet'!B21")
```

The Balance Sheet portion of the name will be consistent, so I'll leave that. I'll need to change the B to refer to the proper year. I'll start by making that variable. The letter B is 66 in the ASCII character set.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A2&" Balance Sheet'!"&CHAR(66)&"21")
```

Now I can add whatever year I want to 66 to increment that. My year is in column B, but it has a lot of crud around it. First I need to isolate the numeric portion

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"T-",""),"yr","")
```

That gets rid of the stuff around the number. Then I use `VALUE` to turn it into a number. I can add that number to 66 so that T-1yr refers to 67 which is C.

And that's it. It's a little painful to set up, but once it's done, you just copy it down. Note the Div/0 errors means you don't have data for that year. Once you're formulas are working the way you want, wrap it in an `IFERROR()` function to hide those.

In your example, the company name is not repeated on every row. That doesn't work well for this method, but you can have a column where the company is repeated a simply hide that column if your particular presentation is important.

Other things you can with hidden columns: Put in the sheet's name if you don't consistent sheet names or if you just want the formula to be a little easier to read. You could also put the 21 and 51 in hidden columns and refer to those in your indirect function.